# Div that doesnt cover its content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have really strange problem.
I have got webpage, that load from ajax second page into Content Div. 
The main problem, is that Content div doesn't care about covering all items in him.

[image: IMG here.]

There is Code:

```css
.Main_Loaded {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 99%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 90px;
    background-color: grey;
    height: auto;
    align-self: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 2;
    animation: Colour_Change_Grey;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    transition: all 1s;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.Main_Loaded .Title {
    margin-top: 30px;
    height: 15%;
}

.Main_Loaded .Title span {
    font: Serfi;
    font-size: 16px;
    animation: Show_up;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-duration: 3s;
}

.Main_Loaded .Content {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height: 80%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.Main_Loaded .Content #Image {
    min-height: 700px;
    width: 45%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 3px solid black;
    animation: Show_up;
    animation-duration: 3s;
}

.Main_Loaded .Content #Image img {
    animation: Show_up;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-delay: 2s;
}

.Main_Loaded .Content #Info {
    animation: Show_up;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    border: 3px solid white;
    width: 55%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Main_Loaded">
<div class="Title">
  <span>
  Nasza oferta
  </span>
</div>
<div class="Content">
  <div id="Image">

    <div class="owl-carousel">
      <img class="img" class="owl-lazy" src="img/1.jpg" />
      <img class="img" class="owl-lazy" src="img/2.jpg" />
      <img class="img" class="owl-lazy" src="img/3.jpg" />
      <img class="img" class="owl-lazy" src="img/4.jpg" />
      <img class="img" class="owl-lazy" src="img/5.jpg" />
      <img class="img" class="owl-lazy" src="img/6.jpg" />
      <img class="img" class="owl-lazy" src="img/7.jpg" />
      <img class="img" class="owl-lazy" src="img/8.jpg" />
      <img class="img" class="owl-lazy" src="img/9.jpg" />
      <img class="img" class="owl-lazy" src="img/10.jpg" />
      <img class="img" class="owl-lazy" src="img/11.jpg" />
      <img class="img" class="owl-lazy" src="img/12.jpg" />
      <img class="img" class="owl-lazy" src="img/13.jpg" />
      <img class="img" class="owl-lazy" src="img/14.jpg" />
      <img class="img" class="owl-lazy" src="img/15.jpg" />
      <img class="img" class="owl-lazy" src="img/16.jpg" />
      <img class="img" class="owl-lazy" src="img/17.jpg" />
      <img class="img" class="owl-lazy" src="img/18.jpg" />
      <img class="img" class="owl-lazy" src="img/19.jpg" />
      <img class="img" class="owl-lazy" src="img/20.jpg" />
      <img class="img" class="owl-lazy" src="img/22.jpg" />
      <img class="img" class="owl-lazy" src="img/21.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="Info">
    dfsdfdsfdsdsadasdasfgjdfklgndfgjbdklfjgnhdklfjghklj
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And there is page, to see error.[DELETED]

Comment: *"Content div doesn't care about covering all items in him"* - I'm not too sure what this means. But your `#image` div has `overflow: hidden;`, meaning the div will not expand to fit its contents, it will instead just hide whatever doesn't fit.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but the problem is in Main_Loaded div.... Look the page that I posted at the end of my post

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I have no idea what _"Content div doesn't care about covering all items in him"_ means, its very cryptic. Please explain this better

Comment: Or check Screenshot

Comment: @MarcinWawrzków I have seen the screenshot and still have no idea what you want to accomplish. Help us help you by providing more detail

Comment: @zgood look at the screenshot. You can see black border. it's Image div. Main_Loaded should match his height to Image div... :/

Comment: @zgood I believe the issue is that the gray div is not expanding to hold the entire height of the black-border div.

Comment: @MarcinWawrzków That is a better description of your problem. That is because you have your `Main_Loaded` div set to `position: absolute` change it to `position: relative` so that it will still asumme the height of its children... i.e. `Image` div

Comment: @zgood Yeah, Then Main_Loaded start expanding himself, but i've got animations on him and now, when I deleted this line, he blinks at changing his class(JQuery animation). How do I supposed to fix that?

Comment: @MarcinWawrzków Being that your snippet (when you expand it to "Full Page") works just as you'd like, it would seem to me that something you're neglecting to mention or include is the cause of your problem.

Comment: @Santi I have to do something like that. [link](http://imgur.com/a/9gJqZ) in Main_Loaded obviously

Comment: @Santi Yeah, I know, but when I use JQuery ajax to load page from another file it does not do what it should.

Comment: Should I add code from first file? (JQuery included?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is JQuery AJAX.
After copy content into one file, and left code as is, the scripts start working :)